# Question about the proof of 7.6.b in Lin & Bai's Probbaility inequalities (2010)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality

I am reading the proof of 7.6.b in *Probability Inequalities* (by Zhengyan Lin and Zhidong Bai). And I have some questions about the first line of this proof.

[image]

Here $1<p<2$ and $q=p/(p-1)$.

I think the authors use the inequality
$$
\color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^m j^{-1/p} \leqslant q m^{1/q}}.\tag{*}
$$
My question is how to verify this inequality (*).

Comment: Compare the sum with $\int_1^{m} x^{-1/p}dx$.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

According to @geetha290krm's kind comment, we have
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m j^{-1/p} \leqslant 1+\int_1^m x^{-1/p}\mathrm{d}x=1+(qm^{1/q}-1)=qm^{1/q},
$$
where $1/q+1/p=1$.